# Proof of $-\frac{1}{4}$ upper bound to the spectrum of $\Delta$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Picture below is from this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214429509). I don't know how to get the inequation 1. Because in the inequation 2, $f'$ is the derivative of $f(y)$, there is not $\partial_{xx}f$. Even though integrate inequation 2 , I can't get inequation 1. How to get it ?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In equation $(1)$ the function $f$ is assumed to be smooth and compactly supported.  Thus
$$
\int_H \partial_x^2 f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \partial_x^2 f(x,y) dx dy  =0
$$
since for a fixed $y >0$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \partial_x^2 f(x,y) dx = \lim_{T \to \infty} \partial_x f(x,y) \Big\vert^{x=T}_{x=-T} =0
$$
due to the fact that the support of $f$ is compact.  Hence for such $f$
$$
\int_H \Delta f(x,y) dx dy = \int_H \partial_y^2 f(x,y) dx dy,
$$
and so you can use equation $(2)$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my second equation.  It was supposed to be $\partial_x^2$ instead of $\partial_x$.  Then the vanishing of this integral follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus since $\partial_x f(\pm T,y) =0$ for $T>0$ sufficiently large.